# How to transition with ng-repeat vertically stacked div elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have 3 div elements, vertically stacked.

If the top one is removed, I want the bottom ones to move to the top but with a transition of 1 sec and not immediately.

Below is my code pen and the code

https://codepen.io/DhawalSawla/pen/qKgZdd

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div class="outer-box">
      <div class="feed" ng-repeat="f in data.feeds">
        {{f}}
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all s linear;
  position: relative;
}
.feed {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  position: absolute;
}

.feed:first-of-type {
  animation-name: display;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.feed:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 100px;
}

.feed:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 200px;
}

@keyframes display {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.data = {
    feeds: []
  };
  $scope.data.feeds = [];
  $scope.data.feeds.push('Feed 1');
  $scope.data.feeds.push('Feed 2');
  $scope.data.feeds.push('Feed 3');

  setInterval(function() {
    if ($scope.data.feeds.length > 0) {
      console.log('splice1');
      $scope.data.feeds.splice(0,1);
      console.log($scope.data.feeds);
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  }, 1000);
}]);
```

I am trying to create a news feed and this feature is essential for that.

Kindly let me know what wrong am I doing.

Comment: Please insert your code directly into the question instead of directing to external links.

Comment: See [AngularJS ngAnimate Module Reference - CSS-based Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#css-based-animations). CSS-based animations with `ngAnimate` are unique since they require no JavaScript code at all. By using a CSS class that we reference between our HTML and CSS code we can create an animation that will be picked up by AngularJS when an underlying directive performs an operation.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/0f7s9cdu/